# SpringMVC variables not carrying into View

Tags: spring, jsp

I am new to Spring and was trying to setup a basic Web App using the Spring Framework. But I am facing an issue where the message variables are not being passed to the view -- the jsp doesn't show the messages.

Following is my code -

Controller.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller

public class HomeController {
        @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/")
    public String index(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("index");
        String message = new String("Hello Welcome - Please click to login");
        System.out.println(message);
        mav.addObject("message", message);
            return "index";
    }
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:url value="login" var="somevar" />
<h1>Click here to </h1> <a href= "${somevar}">${1+1}</a>  
 <c:out value="${message}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

The evaluation works all fine - but the string for the variable 'message's comes as empty.

Am I missing something? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `index()` controller method is returning a `String`, rather than a `ModelAndView` object. Try:

```
public ModelAndView index(ModelAndView mav){
    mav.setViewName("index");
    String message = new String("Hello Welcome - Please click to login");
    System.out.println(message);
    mav.addObject("message", message);
    return mav;
}
```

Comment: Controller methods are allowed to return `String`s which indicate the view name, however a `Model` object should originate in the method signature.

Answer (score 3):

You must take model from your page. Try the below code:

```
@Controller
public class UpdateController {

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/")
public String index(Model model){
    String message = new String("Hello Welcome - Please click to login");
    System.out.println(message);
    model.addAttribute("message", message);
    return "index";
    }
}
```